# How to convert Java's SecretKeySpec "DESede" to VB.NET?

Tags: java, vb.net, tripledes

I'm having trouble converting the java code to VB.NET

```
SecretKeySpec skey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "DESede");
```

any idea ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim skey As SecretKeySpec = New SecretKeySpec(key, "DESede")
```

Of course, getting this to work properly depends on how you translated the `SecretKeySpec` definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function GenerateTripleDesKey() As Byte()
    Dim rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider()
    Dim tripleDesKey As Byte() = New Byte(23) {}
    rng.GetBytes(tripleDesKey)
    For i As Integer = 0 To tripleDesKey.Length - 1
        Dim keyByte As Integer = tripleDesKey(i) And &HFE
        Dim parity = 0
        Dim b As Integer = keyByte
        While b <> 0
            parity = parity Xor b And 1
            b >>= 1
        End While
        tripleDesKey(i) = CByte(keyByte Or (If(parity = 0, 1, 0)))
    Next
    Return tripleDesKey
End Function
```